# how to set func with boolean?

Tags: swift, function, validation

> I'm stuck validating textfields on the form screen. I don't want to allow requests to be thrown even if one of the textfields is empty. I want to show warning message for empty textfield. If all conditions are met, I would like to submit a request.

```
func isValid() -> Bool {
    if nameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false  {
        nameWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
  
        
    }
    else {
        nameWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
       

    }
    if surnameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
        surnameWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        surnameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
       
    }
    else {
        surnameWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        surnameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        
    }
    if cellPhoneTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
        phoneWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        cellPhoneTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
        
        
    }
    else {
        phoneWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        cellPhoneTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        
    }
    if isChecked == true {

        agreementCheckBoxButton.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
        
    }
    else {
      
        agreementCheckBoxButton.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        
    }
    
    if  isChecked == true || (nameTextField.text?.count ?? 0) > 2 || (surnameTextField.text?.count ?? 0) > 2 || (cellPhoneTextField.text?.count ?? 0) < 10  {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

> If this function returns true or false, I will send a request to the
> service.
> I am sharing the code block with you below

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your question, it's hard to understand what is exactly that you're asking. This guide may help: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BOOL` variable within your function. Set the default value to `true`, and when it runs into an `else` condition, set it to `false`. Finally, at the end of your function, return the value of your `BOOL` variable. If all of the positive conditions are met, it will return the default value of `true`, otherwise return `false`.

```
func isValid() -> Bool {

    //Declare Variable
    var sendRequest:Bool = true

    //Check Name Text Field
    if nameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false  {
        nameWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
    } else {
        nameWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        nameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        sendRequest = false
    }

    //Check Surname Text Field
    if surnameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
        surnameWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        surnameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor
    } else {
        surnameWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        surnameTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        sendRequest = false
    }

    //Check Cell Phone Text Field
    if cellPhoneTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
        phoneWarningLabel.isHidden = true
        cellPhoneTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor   
    } else {
        phoneWarningLabel.isHidden = false
        cellPhoneTextField.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        sendRequest = false
    }

    //Check Agreement Check Box
    if isChecked == true {
        agreementCheckBoxButton.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_222_222_222()?.cgColor  
    } else {   
        agreementCheckBoxButton.layer.borderColor = R.color.rgb_249_36_23()?.cgColor
        sendRequest = false      
    }
    
    //Return Variable
    return sendRequest 

}
```